# When using os-uninstaller It says I have to use a live usb to proceed. Is there another way of doing this?

Tags: uninstall, system

I'm trying to uninstall Ubuntu with the OS uninstaller, and I am facing a problem. The uninstaller says I need to have a USB or live USB and I was wondering if there was another way to remove Ubuntu from my computer.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there was another way to remove Ubuntu from my computer

You can only remove an operating system from another operating system. An active operating system can not be removed.

The advice they give are the 2 easiest methods that will work for anyone regardless of how many operating systems they have. But you can also remove an operating system from another operating system. Boot up Mac OS or Windows and remove the partitions of that operating system you want removed.

Besides that you can also use a [gParted Live DVD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) instead of the Ubuntu Live DVD or Live USB.

A little more difficult and would require a bit of setting it up: you can also do this from an installer you put on a different partition. Create a partition the size of the Ubuntu ISO. Put the ISO in that partition. Reboot. Enter grub menu and boot from the ISO. During the installation part you can delete any partition.

But I would assume you want to install another operating system. If so, see the installation procedure of that installation on how to remove the current operating system.

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to uninstall the running system?

If you have another system on your computer, you could use that to delete ubuntu's partition(s).

If you haven't installed something else but would like to, just delete the partition(s) during the  installation.

Comment: Please tell me, what is wrong with this answer?